# Can I find x and y coordinates for the vertices of an octagon with sides of unequal lengths and angles?

Tags: geometry

Knowing only the lengths of the sides, which are: 4.283, 4.227, 4.259, 4.259, 4.226, 4.246, 4.251, 4.248, can I find the x and y points of the vertices to within three decimal places? If so, how? I have a grade 10 level understanding of math.

After reading the replies, I can see how knowing only the lengths of the sides isn't enough. What if I knew the distances across opposite vertices?

Comment: No. You can't determine the shape of an octagon from the lengths of its sides. You can't even determine the shape of a quadrilateral from the lengths of its sides. You need more data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Basically for any polygon with four or more sides, you can squish it and move the vertices.  Triangles are rigid, as shown by side-side-side.

Comment: Of course! I would need angles.